# Best practice for using php file with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm beginning web development with php and am testing jQuery ajax calls to a php file to run functions. But I've noticed that the php file loads into the resources each time I call it with an AJAX POST method. What is the best solution to prevent this occurrence? Also, are there better coding practices to use when performing multiple function calls (what I'm used to calling web services or web methods in the c# world) from a single file in php?

**test.php**

```
<?php
    if($_POST['action']=='test'){
        $arr = array(
            'stack'=>'overflow',
            'key'=>'value'
        );
        echo json_encode($arr);
   }
?>
```

**scripts.js**

```
function postTest(){
    var data = {
        action: 'test'
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "test.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data,
        success: function(result){
            console.log(result)
        }
    });
}
```

Update:
I changed my code to use the data variable as an object in the ajax call.
The original question still stands however. How do I use a function inside a php file without it being loaded into the site resources in the browser for each ajax call?

Thank you.

Comment: Don’t use `JSON.stringify` on your data, but pass the object directly … jQuery will take care of the rest.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by multiple function calls.

Comment: Am I wrong for thinking I should use a single php file to store several server-side functions (like web methods)? This is what I am trying to do. With JavaScript handling events front-end to pass data to a server-side function.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. What I usually do is I structure my php files with a RESTful API structure. So if I want to create a user, I would send a post to /users/create.php. If I want to delete a user, I'd send it to /users/delete.php etc

Comment: Okay. Thank you very much. I don't have much knowledge of practices used when working with php. I will look into what you have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

If you're noticing that the php block is never getting executed, then you're passing in the data wrong. Try this:

```
function postTest(){
  var data = {
    'action': 'test'
  };
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "test.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data,
    success: function(result){
      console.log(result)
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Also, notice I turned action into a string in the json.

Comment: by json you mean object and its only necessary if the property name is a reserved word

Comment: @andrew I do mean the object 'data'. I just think it's good practise to avoid confusion, because he might have action defined elsewhere earlier.

Comment: @zsawaf: That’s nonsense, even if he had a variable named `action` in the current scope, that would not matter here, because the key is taken literally and not interpreted as a possible variable name.

Answer (score 0):

JSON.stringify is not working in your favor, here.

To demonstrate this, you could put `print_r($_POST)` in your php script and see what `console.log(result)` gives you.

To remedy this, you can simply put your data in the `$.ajax()` block:

```
function postTest(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "test.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
           action: 'test'
        },
        success: function(result){
            console.log(result)
        }
    });
}
```